# SimpleMembership with custom table using EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first, simplemembership

I was following HTML5 Line of business course on pluralsight to use Simple membership.  I use the same code but getting error while Creating account using SimpleMembership with custom table.  I cant find whats wrong in it.  Can anybody help?

> Invalid column name 'ConfirmationToken'. 
> Invalid column name
>   'PasswordChangedDate'. 
> Invalid column name
>   'PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess'.

Here is my code

**Register Method:**

```
  public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password,
                        new
                        {
                            FirstName = "Admin",
                            LastName = "Admin",
                            IsActive = true,
                            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                            ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now
                        });
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }
```

**Entities:**

```
 public class Membership 
    {
        public int UserId {get; set;}
        public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmationTokeen { get; set; }
        public bool? IsConfirmed { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastPaswordFailureDate { get; set; }
        public int PasswordFailureSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PasswordChangeDate { get; set; }
        public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public string PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate { get; set; }
    }

public class OAuthMembership 
    {
        public string  Provider { get; set; }
        public string ProviderUserId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
public class Role
    {
        public int RoleId {get; set;}
        public string RoleName {get; set;}

        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

        public Role()
        {
            this.Users = new List<User>();
        }
    }
  public class User : IAuditInfo
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}

        public string Username{get; set;}

        public string FirstName {get; set;}
        public string LastName { get; set; }


        public bool IsActive{get; set;}

        public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedOn {get; set;}

         public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            this.Roles = new List<Role>();
        }
    }
```

**Configuration**

```
 public UserConfiguration()
        {
            this.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnOrder(0);
            this.Property(p => p.Username).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
            this.Property(p => p.FirstName).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(100);
            this.Property(p => p.LastName).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(100);

            this.HasMany(a => a.Roles).WithMany(b => b.Users).Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                m.ToTable("webpages_UsersInRoles");
            });
        }

 public RoleConfiguration()
        {
            this.ToTable("webpages_Roles");
            this.Property(p => p.RoleName).HasMaxLength(256).HasColumnType("nvarchar").IsRequired();
        }

 public OAuthMembershipConfiguration()
        {
            this.ToTable("webpages_OAuthMembership");
            this.HasKey(k => new { k.Provider, k.ProviderUserId });
            this.Property(p => p.Provider).HasMaxLength(128).HasColumnType("nvarchar").IsRequired();
            this.Property(p => p.ProviderUserId).HasMaxLength(128).HasColumnType("nvarchar").IsRequired();
            this.Property(p => p.UserId).IsRequired();
        }

public MembershipConfiguration()
        {
            this.ToTable("webpages_Membership");
            this.HasKey(s => s.UserId);
            this.Property(p => p.UserId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
            this.Property(p => p.ConfirmationTokeen).HasMaxLength(128).HasColumnType("nvarchar");
            this.Property(p => p.PasswordFailureSinceLastSuccess).IsRequired();
            this.Property(p => p.Password).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128).HasColumnType("nvarchar");
            this.Property(p => p.PasswordSalt).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128).HasColumnType("nvarchar");
            this.Property(p => p.PasswordVerificationToken).HasMaxLength(128).HasColumnType("nvarchar");
        }
```

**Filter:**

> public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
>               {
>
> ```
>             DataContext context = new DataContext();
>             context.Database.Initialize(true);
>
>             try
>             {
>                     if (!context.Database.Exists())
>                     {
>                         ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
>                     }
>                 WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
>                     Config.ConnectionStringName, 
>                     Config.UsersTableName, 
>                     Config.UsersPrimaryKeyColumnName, 
>                     Config.UsersUsernameColumnName, 
>                     autoCreateTables: true);
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>             }
>         }
> ```

Comment: ConfirmationTokeen != ConfirmationToken && PasswordChangeDate !=PasswordChangedDate && PasswordFailureSinceLastSuccess!=PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess :)

Comment: @thanks for correcting it has only spelling mistakes rest is working fine

Comment: no prop...home it helps.

Comment: So, is there still a problem?

Comment: @Gret Arnold, no problem resolved